# How to implement a background with overlayed text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There's a feature on Facebook where one makes a post by selecting a background color or an image than writing some text on it. How can I replicate this with flutter such that the background is stored together with the text on it?
Here is the link to an image of what I am trying to create.
[image]

Comment: Well, u can make a new class with 2 variables; text (String) and backgroundColor (Color) and store the data that way

Answer (score 0):

Give some ideas:

1. Stack your Image and Textfield (textfield without border & transparent background
2. Wrap this stack with [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) for printing the final image

Answer (score 0):

Use stack then background image and text field.

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new Scaffold(
  body: new Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("images/background.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover,),
      ),
    ),
    new Center(
      child: new TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "What's on your mind",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
             ),)
           ],
          )
         );
        }
```